# How can I change the table adapter's command timeout

Tags: c#, dataset, timeout, command

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with C#.

I have a .xsd file and it has a table adapter. I want to change the table adapter's command timeout.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have investigated this issue a bit today and come up with the following solution based on a few sources.
The idea is to create a base class for the table adapter too inherit which increases the timeout for all commands in the table adapter without having to rewrite too much existing code. It has to use reflection since the generated table adapters don't inherit anything useful. It exposes a public function to alter the timeout if you want to delete what i used in the constructor and use that.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CSP
{
    public class TableAdapterBase : System.ComponentModel.Component
    {
        public TableAdapterBase()
        {
            SetCommandTimeout(GetConnection().ConnectionTimeout);
        }

        public void SetCommandTimeout(int Timeout)
        {
            foreach (var c in SelectCommand())
                c.CommandTimeout = Timeout;
        }

        private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            return GetProperty("Connection") as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
        }

        private SqlCommand[] SelectCommand()
        {
            return GetProperty("CommandCollection") as SqlCommand[];
        }

        private Object GetProperty(String s)
        {
            return this.GetType().GetProperty(s, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How this can be consumed!

Answer (score 14):

With some small modifications csl's idea works great.

```
partial class FooTableAdapter
{
  /**
   * <summary>
   * Set timeout in seconds for Select statements.
   * </summary>
   */
  public int SelectCommandTimeout
  {
    set
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.CommandCollection.Length; i++)
                if (this.CommandCollection[i] != null)
                 this.CommandCollection[i].CommandTimeout = value;
    }
  }
}
```

To use it, just set 
this.FooTableAdapter.CommandTimeout = 60; somewhere before the this.FooTableAdapter.Fill();

---

If you need to change the timeout on a lot of table adapters, you could create a generic extension method and have it use reflection to change the timeout.

```
/// <summary>
/// Set the Select command timeout for a Table Adapter
/// </summary>
public static void TableAdapterCommandTimeout<T>(this T TableAdapter, int CommandTimeout) where T : global::System.ComponentModel.Component
{                
    foreach (var c in typeof(T).GetProperty("CommandCollection", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(TableAdapter, null) as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand[])
        c.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout;
}
```

Usage:

```
this.FooTableAdapter.TableAdapterCommandTimeout(60);
this.FooTableAdapter.Fill(...);
```

This is a little slower.  And there is the possibility of an error if you use it on the wrong type of object.  (As far as I know, there is no "TableAdapter" class that you could limit it to.)

Comment: It works very well! thank you for helping me with your post about 10 years ago lol

Answer (score 9):

I had a couple of issues with using Mitchell Gilman's solution that I was eventually able to workaround.

First of all, I needed to make sure to use the right namespace. It took me a while to figure out that Designer file for the xsd data set actually contains two namespaces, one for the data set in general and one for the table adapters. So the first thing is to note is that the namespace for the table adapter should be used, not for the data set in general.

Secondly, the commandcollection may not always be initialized when the timeout command is used for the first time. To work around this, I called the InitCommandCollection command if this was the case.

So the adapted solution I used was

```
namespace xxx.xxxTableAdapters

partial class FooTableAdapter
{
  /**
   * <summary>
   * Set timeout in seconds for Select statements.
   * </summary>
   */
  public int SelectCommandTimeout
  {
    set
    {
        if (this.CommandCollection == null)
                this.InitCommandCollection();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.CommandCollection.Length; i++)
            if (this.CommandCollection[i] != null)
             this.CommandCollection[i].CommandTimeout = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that's helpful to people!

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you cannot access members like *Adapter* in your class, since they are defined as *private* to the class.

Fortunately, the wizard will generate partial classes, which means you can extend them.  As described in [this thread by Piebald][1], you can write your own property to set the timeout on select-commands.

Generally, you would do this:

```
partial class FooTableAdapter
{
  /**
   * <summary>
   * Set timeout in seconds for Select statements.
   * </summary>
   */
  public int SelectCommandTimeout
  {
    set
    {
      for ( int n=0; n < _commandCollection.Length; ++n )
        if ( _commandCollection[n] != null )
          ((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)_commandCollection[n])
            .commandTimeout = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I have not actually tried this myself, but it seems like a viable solution.

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't able to get this to work for me because _commandCollection was null.  I made some updates and posted that as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Say your dataset is called MySET.
There is one table called MyTable

```
MySETTableAdapters.MyTableTableAdapter fAdapter = 
   new MySETTableAdapters.MyTableTableAdapter();
fAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = <fill inyour value here>;
```

Comment: -1 This won't work since a strongly typed `TableAdapter` does not expose the `Adapter` property, it is `private`. So the only way apart from refelction is to extend the partial class of the `TableAdapter` to make it public.

Answer (score 1):

Call ChangeTimeout Function by providing the TableAdapter and Time in seconds.

```
this.ChangeTimeout(this.taTest, 500);
```

Function :

```
 private void ChangeTimeout(Component component, int timeout)
{
    if (!component.GetType().FullName.Contains("TableAdapter")) { 
        return;
    }

    PropertyInfo adapterProp = component.GetType().GetProperty("CommandCollection", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (adapterProp == null) {
        return;
    }

    SqlCommand[] command = adapterProp.GetValue(component, null) as SqlCommand[];

    if (command == null) {
        return;
    }

    Interaction.command(0).CommandTimeout = timeout;
}
```

Comment: What is Interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example code from [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/16/increasetableadapterquerytimeout.aspx), using VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Namespace MyDataSetTableAdapters
    Partial Class CustomersTableAdapter
        Public Sub SetCommandTimeOut(ByVal timeOut As Integer)
            For Each command As SqlCommand In Me.CommandCollection
                command.CommandTimeout = timeOut
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

When it comes time to call a long query, just call the SetCommandTimeOut method before the query:

```
Dim ds As New MyDataSet
Dim customersTA As New MyDataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter
' Increase time-out to 60 seconds
customersTA.SetCommandTimeOut(60000)
' Do the slow query
customersTA.FillSlowQuery(ds.Customers)
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a more convenient way to do this. Here's a quick recap of what I found.

Let's say I add a (class library) project called MyDB to my solution. Into that project I add a DataSet called "Data". And into that dataset, I drag a table called "X".

What I get on the design surface is an object that shows that I have an object called "XTableAdapter".

I now open the generated code, Data.Designer.cs, and look for XTableAdapter.
When I find it, I note that it's contained in namespace MyDB.DataTableAdapters - which is just a concatenation of the name of the project, "MyDB", the name of the DataSet, "Data", and "TableAdapters".

With that in hand, I now go back to the class library, still called Class1.cs (which I'll ignore for now).

I change its namespace from MyDB to MyDB.DataTableAdapters.

I change the class declaration to **public partial class XTableAdapter**,
and make it look like this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MyDB.DataTableAdapters
{
    public partial class XTableAdapter
    {
        public void SetTimeout(int seconds)
        {
            foreach (SqlCommand cmd in CommandCollection)
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = seconds;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The calling sequence could hardly be clearer:

```
int TwoMinutes = 120;    
XTableAdapter.SetTimeout(TwoMinutes);
```

Less muss, less fuss, less reflection (well, none), less filling.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a partial class, make you have the right namespace. Probably [your data set's name] + "TableAdapters'. Example:

namespace MyProject.DataSet1TableAdapters

Answer (score 0):

You can open up the Properties folder, open Settings.settings and alter the Timeout property of your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I do like this ; Right click `Fill()`  or `GetX()` function and click `Goto Defination` from menu.

You will see Source code of DATATABLE. And find ;

```
private global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand[] _commandCollection;
```

command line from your dataadapter class. 
And Change the private to public .

Now you can access the _commandCollection and you can change all attributes.

But be careful when you add or change any Filed form DESIGNER , the public will be private again by autogenerate system.

And also , when you finish to call Fill or Get Function you must reset `_commandColleciton`  calling this function ( `InitCommandCollection()` )

```
 public void InitCommandCollection() {}
```

This function is also private by autogen, you must change to public also!

Example:

```
dsIslemlerTableAdapters.tblIslemlerTableAdapter _t = new dsIslemlerTableAdapters.tblIslemlerTableAdapter();

dsIslemler.tblIslemlerDataTable _m = new dsIslemler.tblIslemlerDataTable();

_t._commandCollection[0].CommandText = "Select * From tblIslemler Where IslemTarihi>='' And IslemTarihi<=''";

_m = _t.GetData();

_t.InitCommandCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit old now and suspect this solution is not relevant to everyone, but I've ended up using [AniPol's](/users/2724446/anipol) solution to override the ObjectDataSource control as follows:

```
public class MyObjectDataSource : ObjectDataSource
{
    public MyObjectDataSource()
    {
        this.ObjectCreated += this.MyObjectDataSource_ObjectCreated;
    }

    private void MyObjectDataSource_ObjectCreated(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        var objectDataSourceView = sender as ObjectDataSourceView;
        if (objectDataSourceView != null && objectDataSourceView.TypeName.EndsWith("TableAdapter"))
        {
            var adapter = e.ObjectInstance;

            PropertyInfo adapterProp = adapter.GetType()
                .GetProperty(
                    "CommandCollection",
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (adapterProp == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            SqlCommand[] commandCollection = adapterProp.GetValue(adapter, null) as SqlCommand[];

            if (commandCollection == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd in commandCollection)
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the already very useful answers for tableadapters that helped me a lot, I also had the need to read out the actual timeout value. Thus:

```
namespace XTrans.XferTableAdapters
{

    public partial class FooTableAdapter
    {
        int? _timeout = null;

        ///<summary>
        ///Get or set the current timeout in seconds for Select statements.
        ///</summary>
        public int CurrentCommandTimeout
        {
            get
            {
                int timeout = 0;

                if (_timeout != null)
                {
                    timeout = (int)_timeout;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.CommandCollection.Length; i++)
                        if (this.CommandCollection[i] != null)
                            timeout = this.CommandCollection[i].CommandTimeout;
                }
                return timeout;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.CommandCollection == null)
                    this.InitCommandCollection();

                for (int i = 0; i < this.CommandCollection.Length; i++)
                    if (this.CommandCollection[i] != null)
                    {
                        this.CommandCollection[i].CommandTimeout = value;
                        _timeout = value;
                    }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [name of DataSet].Designer.cs which is a file added under the data set file in the solution and then search for :

```
 private void InitCommandCollection();
```

This is a function that you should be able to set properties for functions that have been defined in a table adapter.

The first line in that function is

```
this._commandCollection = new global::System.Data.IDbCommand[<number of function defined in a table adapater>];
```

and then in the next line for each of those function, you can set

```
((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)(this._commandCollection[<index>])).CommandTimeout = 0;
```

which 0 indicates no limitation and the function will not stop due to the time out and also it can be set to 10, 20, 30 or 1000 and so on

Answer (score 0):

After scratching my head all day long I finally got the resolution for this. After designing your .xsd file all you need to do is go to your dataset.designer.cs page which is an auto generated page and change the code to provided below. It really works. Give it a try.

```
protected global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand[] CommandCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._commandCollection == null))
            {
                this.InitCommandCollection();
                _commandCollection[0].CommandTimeout = 0;
            }
            _commandCollection[0].CommandTimeout = 0;
            return this._commandCollection;
        }
    }
```