# How to change timeout on TableAdapter for table-valued function?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a TableAdapter generated by the Visual Studio dataset designer.

Owing to some *fabulous* coding by my illustrious predecessor, this stored function returns a mountain of data, and I'm trying to solve that problem, but in the meantime, the procedure is timing out because all of the data isn't returned by the time the connection is set to time out.

`myProcedureTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand` is `null` at runtime, as are `DeleteCommand`, `InsertCommand` and `UpdateCommand`. The variable I want is contained in `myProcedureTableAdapter.CommandCollection[0]`, but that's protected.

How can I extend the timeout on this TableAdapter?

**EDIT:** I can actually run the Fill and GetData commands on the TableAdapter, so the select command obviously exists in some context (i.e. as a member of `CommandCollection`), I just can't access that command via the `SelectCommand` property.

**EDIT2:** Well, this is vexing. I've gone into the generated code and found the following:

```
Public Overloads Overridable Function GetData() As DataSet_myDataSet.myProcedureDataTable
    Me.Adapter.SelectCommand = Me.CommandCollection(0)
```

This shows that the `SelectCommand` isn't being set until I'm actually *in the process* of selecting stuff. This is insane.

I'm going to try creating a `readonly` property in a partial class, and have that directly reference `Me.CommandCollection(0)`. It's terrible coding practice, but I can't see any other option at this point.

I'll leave this question here in case someone comes along with a sane idea.

Comment: I think the question [might be a duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192171/how-can-i-change-table-adapters-command-time-out). Does that help?

Comment: For some reason, the SelectCommand property isn't initialised. The command that *is* the SelectCommand is initialised, and is present in the `CommandCollection`, but `CommandCollection` is a protected property. I can't decide if I'm doing something stupid, or if the code isn't being generated properly.