# Change timeout for table adapter (call stored procedure) in Visual Studio 2012 VB project?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, tableadapter

**My problem**: Call to a Stored Procedure is timing out after 30 seconds. Seems the auto-generated table adapter doesn't provide an interface to change it.

**Question**: How can I change the timeout value for my SP call?

**Environment**: Visual Studio 2012, Code in VB.NET, database: SQL Server 2008 R2. I am using a dataset with the DataSet Designer for CRUD operations and also calling Store Procedures. The auto-generated table adapters are called from code.

**Research already done**: I have found some answers for C# projects, but I have little experience in the language: [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192171/how-can-i-change-table-adapters-command-time-out/9734717#9734717)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a strongly typed `TableAdapter` which just holds the `DataAdapter` as `protected` property, you cannot change all `SqlCommand`'s [`CommandTimeout`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) directly. What you can do is to extend this autogenerated class(it's a `Partial Class`). Therefore create another class with the same name in the same directory, for example: `Public Partial Class YourTableAdapter`.

Now you're able to create new properties or methods which can access the `DataDapter`. Note that the class has to sit in the same (autogenerated) namespace. For example:

```
Namespace ApplicationName.DataSetNameTableAdapters
    Partial Public Class YourTableAdapter
        Public Property CommandTimeout As Int32
            Get
                Return Me.CommandCollection(0).CommandTimeout
            End Get
            Set(value As Int32)
                For Each cmd As SqlCommand In Me.CommandCollection
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = value
                Next
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End NameSpace
```

Don't extend the original class (`.designer.vb`), it will be overwritten on every change in the designer.

Now you are able to do:

```
Dim adapter = new YourTableAdapter()
adapter.CommandTimeout = 60 * 30  ' 30 minutes
```

Comment: That worked for me, thanks! I just had to declare "cmd" as "cmd As SqlCommand".

Comment: @DanielHillebrand: i've approved the edit. But it compiles for me since [arrays implement `IEnumerable(Of T)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773740/why-do-arrays-in-net-only-implement-ienumerable-and-not-ienumerablet) you don't need to cast it. You don't have set `Option Infer` to _on_ in the compiler settings. Use `As` if the type does not implement `IEnumerable(Of T)` but only the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface(like [`DataTable.Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase(v=vs.110).aspx)). The `As` casts the object to the real type.